# testing send_email is not working

Tags: python, django, email

I don't get why when I run the test it's always failed with AssertionError: 0 != 1
 even though the result of r is 1.

```
class UserProfileTaskTest(TestCase):

    def test_send_email(self):
        subject = 'subject'
        body = 'body'
        from_email = 'from_email@test.com'
        recipient_list = ['recipient@test.com']

        r = send_mail(
            subject=subject,
            message=body,
            from_email=from_email,
            recipient_list=recipient_list
        )

        print(r)

        self.assertEqual(len(outbox), 1)
```

Comment: What is outbox?

Comment: I bet they're importing it like this `from django.core.mail import outbox`

Comment: @Brobin yes I import it like that :) I'm just starting learning django I didn't know it was a special attribute.

Comment: @vZ10 Sorry I didn't include it in post I import it from `from django.core.mail import outbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outbox is special type attribute that can't import directly but when you send email using email backend then mail.outbox will work as list and save email data to outbox list. So use below example for testmail is sent or not.

```
from django.core import mail
from django.test import TestCase

class UserProfileTaskTest(TestCase):
    def test_send_email(self):
        subject = 'subject'
        body = 'body'
        from_email = 'from_email@test.com'
        recipient_list = ['recipient@test.com']
        mail.send_mail(
            subject=subject,
            message=body,
            from_email=from_email,
            recipient_list=recipient_list
        )
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
```

When you run above code you have initial `mail.outbox = []`

but after sending email it save `EmailMessage` instance in list.

Comment: Thank you! it's working it's just me didn't read the document enough https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#email-services